# Blazor electron.net app get warning worldSafeExecuteJavaScript

Tags: javascript, blazor, electron.net

I create a Blazor application and build with [Electron.NET](https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET), I get this warning but I can not see the **worldSafeExecuteJavaScript** option in **WebPreferences** so I can not enable it.

```
(electron) Security Warning: webFrame.executeJavaScript was called without worldSafeExecuteJavaScript enabled. This is considered unsafe. worldSafeExecuteJavaScript will be enabled by default in Electron 12.
log @ VM55 renderer_init.js:15
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I have also come up against this problem but despite a good look around and even trying to edit some of the JavaScript files I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Being discussed [on ElectronNET GitHub](https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET/issues/526)